# Biblatex APA Instagram Account

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I'm trying to cite an Instagram profile in biblatex. According to APA 7 it should look like this: [image]

Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution yet. The in text citation should look like this: (National Geographic, n. d.). When I was still using bibtex I could fix it like this:

```
    title={\textit{Posts}},
    author={{Musk, E. [@elonmusk]}},
    firstkey={Musk},
    type={Twitter Profile},
    publisher={Twitter},
    url={https://twitter.com/elonmusk},
    lastchecked={24.09.2020}
}
```

By using `firstkey={}`latex used the correct name for the intext citation in the text, but i don`t think this works in biblatex.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[parsikip=full,oneside, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.8cm, right=2.8cm,top=2.1cm, bottom=19mm,includehead=false,footskip=10mm, bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{microtype}      
\usepackage{color}          


\usepackage[style=apa, datelabel=comp, uniquelist=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{litSM.bib}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linktoc = all, draft = false, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}



\setglossarystyle{listdotted}
\setlength{\glslistdottedwidth}{.6\linewidth}


\clubpenalty=10000                                          % Verhindert einzelne Absatzzeile am Ende oder am Anfang
\widowpenalty=10000                                         % einer Seite.
\displaywidowpenalty=10000                                  %
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}

\newcommand{\anf}[1]{\glqq{}#1{}\grqq{}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
%   \renewcommand{\BCBL}{,}%
%   \renewcommand{\BCBT}{,}%
}


\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=2}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{%
        #1%
        \ifbool{cbx:parens}
        {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
        {}}}

\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \printtext[citehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{cite}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
        or
        ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )
    }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%
    \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
        \usebibmacro{textcite}}}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%%%%% Oxford-Komma vor & %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\addcomma\space\&\space}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\setcounter{page}{1}\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{Einleitung}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need a `.bib` entry for APA style with `biblatex-apa` and you don't know how to deal with it, have a look at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib. That file contains `.bib` entries for all reference examples in the APA manual categorised by chapter, section and example number.

For Instagram posts the relevant entries are [`10.15:107` and `10.15:108` in ll. 2366-2390](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/bf51fec289130300483847b8583d1a09cbed6fce/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib#L2366-L2390)

```
@ONLINE{10.15:107,
  ENTRYSUBTYPE            = {photographs},
  GROUPAUTHOR             = {{Zeitz MOCAA}},
  GROUPAUTHOR+an:username = {1="@zeitzmocaa"},
  TITLE                   = {Grade 6 Learners from {Parkfields} {Primary}
                             {School} in {Hanover} {Park} Visited the
                             Museum for a Tour and Workshop Hosted by},
  EPRINT                  = {Instagram},
  URL                     = {https://www.instagram.com/p/BqpHpjFBs3b},
  DATE                    = {2018-11-26}
}

@ONLINE{10.15:108,
  ENTRYSUBTYPE            = {Highlight},
  GROUPAUTHOR             = {{The New York Public Library}},
  GROUPAUTHOR+an:username = {1="@nypl"},
  TITLE                   = {The Raven},
  EPRINT                  = {Instagram},
  URL                     = {https://bitly.com/2FV8bu3},
  URLDATE                 = {2019-04-16}
}
```

Based on that the Taylor Swift example would be

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{taylor,
  entrysubtype       = {Instagram profile},
  author             = {Taylor Swift},
  author+an:username = {1="@taylorswift"},
  title              = {Posts},
  eprint             = {Instagram},
  url                = {https://www.instagram.com/taylorwsift},
  urldate            = {2020-01-09},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{taylor}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Swift, T. [@taylorswift]. (n.d.). Posts [Instagram profile]. Instagram. Retrieved January 9, 2020, from https://www.instagram.com/taylorwsift]